# Load-Balancing 2 ADSL lines on a Software Level

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing, adsl

We want to load balance two ADSL lines in our office.

I have limited experiences with is and was wondering if someone could provide me with a solution beyond the theory, in other words, specifics about hardware and software requirements and suggestions.

So we have 2 4mb ADSL lines and want to laod-balance them preferably using a linux box. How should this be set up? Obviously each line connects to a modem/router, and then do there routers connect to a switch on which the rest of the LAN and the Linux Box are connected to?

Also, is there any load-balancing software for linux someone could recommend?

Your help is GREATLY appreciated!!!

kidnest regards

Seb

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for your requirement.. You can use Kerio Control for load balancing... it works fine in my environmental.... and you can use TMG Server 2010 for ISP redundancy.... It works extra fine in my case.... I tried both.... and you can try one more thing.... that is WinGate.... i already worked with it.... it works fine too, because of low weight on hard and on ram too.... You can Use it as Firewall too... Excluding TMG .... other two solutions are also available for Linux....